# Preposition : for vs from

Tags: prepositions

1. The widening of Sunnyville Drive *for two lanes to four lanes will take six months.
2. The widening of Sunnyville Drive *from two lanes to four lanes will take six months.

Which sentence is more appropriate?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is the only one the two that is in standard English. I have never heard or seen the word "for" used as it is in option 1. It could be the result of a typographical error compounded by predictive text.

"a —used as a function word to indicate a starting point of a physical movement." part of definition of from on merriam-webster.com

In option 2, "from" indicates the starting condition, rather than a geographical starting point. Just as you can fly from New York to Chicago, Sunnyville Drive can transition from two lanes to four lanes.

Answer (score -1):

> The widening of Sunnyville Drive from two lanes to four will take six
>   months.

The second iteration of "lanes" is superfluous.